# Guardar un UPDATE en una variable

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tengo una duda, quisiera guardar un `UPDATE` dentro de una variable, por ejemplo, este es mi código:

```
    public static function cancelTareasP(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) {    

        $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();    

        $tareasPend = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex);
        $ids = array_column($tareasPend, 'id');    

        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id' AND id = '$id'");
        }

        return regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $idTareasModificadas, $proyecto_id);
    }
```

Al momento de hacer el `UPDATE` se modifica el `estatus` de las tareas, esos cambios deben registrarse en un historial, mi duda es si se puede guardar ese `UPDATE` como una variable (`$idTareasModificadas`) que sea el array de los `id` de las tareas que se modificaron, para poder hacer el registro.

Espero me haya dado a entender.

Comment: Esto huele a tarea como para un Store procedure o un trigger.. podrias aclarar que base de datos estas usando?? y haciendo un select, podrias saber que columnas va a actualizar el update

Comment: ¿Cómo que cuál base de datos estoy usando?

Answer (score 1):

si deseas guardar en un historico los id de las tareas solamente debes colocar la función regHistorico dentro del foreach:

```
public static function cancelTareasP(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) {    

    $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();    
    $tareasPend = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex);
    $ids = array_column($tareasPend, 'id');    

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id' AND id = '$id'");
        regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $id, $proyecto_id);

    }
}
```

Comment: El `$id` es el `id` de todas las tareas con `estatus = 'Pendiente'`, y yo sólo quiero los `id` de las tareas que se han modificado dependiendo del proyecto(`$proyecto_id`) que se haya seleccionado. Al poner el `regHistorico` dentro del `foreach` me arroja todos los `id`.

Comment: Pero si tienes el foreach ($ids as $id)  la variable $ids es donde tienes almacenado todos los ids pendientes de las tareas y al colocar el as $id estas recorriendo id por id, también como veo tu actualización: UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id' AND id = '$id'.    solo estas actualizando un id dentro del foreach ¿Cuál es el problema que también ejecutes el histórico ahí adentro? solo guardaras el histórico para ese id.  Es lo que puedo entenderte.

Comment: Pero ya lo he hecho así, con el `regHistorico` dentro del `foreach` y me arroja todos los `id` de las tareas pendientes, yo sólo quiero los `id` de las tareas a las que se les modificó el `estatus` con el `UPDATE`.

Comment: Y que variable estas consultando? $ids o $id.
te recomiento hacer un echo "<pre>"; var_dump($ids); $exit(); para que veas que esa variable tiene todos los id y un echo "<pre>"; var_dump($id); $exit(); para que verifiques si solo tiene el id que tu necesitas actualizar y guardar en el histórico y nos cuentas.

Comment: Con `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($ids); exit();` si me arroja todos los `id` de las tareas con `estatus = 'Pendiente`. 
Con `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($id); exit();` esto es lo que me arroja:
`string(1) "1"`.

Comment: Exacto ahí solo tienes un id, que es el que necesitas el id 1 lo actualizas y lo guardas en el histórico, luego sigue el ciclo del foreach y te trae otro id que puede ser el 2 lo actualizas y lo guardas en el histórico. debes trabajar con esa variable $id

Comment: Si entiendo lo que me dices, el problema es que sigue arrojándome todos los `id` de tareas Pendientes en vez de sólo aquellas que se modificaron

Answer (score 0):

Podrías mejorar la función getTareasPendientes para obtener las tareas pendientes con el $proyecto_id; así te aseguras que esa función te retorne las tareas pendientes de dicho proyecto o ejecutas el query allí en sustitución de la función, ya que el problema radica en que obtienes todas las tareas pendientes, ejecutando el query allí traerías las que tengan estatus = 'Pendiente' y pertenezcan al proyecto_id.

```
$tareasPend = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, $proyecto_id);
    o
$tareasPend = $conex->query("SELECT id FROM Tareas WHERE estatus = 'Pendiente' AND proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id'");   

foreach ($tareasPend as $id) {
    $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE id = '$id'");
    regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $id, $proyecto_id);
}
```

Comment: Al hacerlo de esa forma no me cancela las tareas que debería y en el registro histórico me arroja el `id` de una tarea que ni siquiera está en el proyecto que seleccioné

Comment: el problema radica en que obtienes todas las tareas pendientes, ejecutando el query allí traerías las que tengan estatus = 'Pendiente' y pertenezcan al proyecto_id.  $tareasPend = $conex->query("SELECT id FROM Tareas WHERE estatus = 'Pendiente' AND proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id'");   

foreach ($tareasPend as $id) {
    $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE id = '$id'");
    regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $id, $proyecto_id);
}

Comment: Ya lo tenía así, ejecutando el query, pero mi jefe me dijo que no era necesario porque ya tenía un método que me arrojaba todas las tareas pendientes, así que tuve que cambiarlo, pero si funciona así, sólo tuve que agregar otra línea de código ya que me marcaba array to string conversion:
`$tareasPend = $conex->query("SELECT id FROM Tareas WHERE estatus = 'Pendiente' AND proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id'");
foreach ($tareasPend as $ids) {
$id = $ids['id'];
$conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE id = '$id'");
regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $id, $proyecto_id);
}`